# how to list Object using findAllBy in grails

Tags: grails

i have my class

```
 class  user{
    .
    .
    .
    Service service
    }
```

and i want display a list of users who have service="direction".
    i try to do this in my view:

```
    Employe.findAllByService("direction")
```

and error is

```
"Employe.findAllByService() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String)"
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass it a service object

```
Employee.findAllByService( Service.load( id ) )
```

where id is the id of the service you're interested in

Answer (score 0):

You have to use an actual object since Service is an object:

```
Service direction = Service.findByName("direction")
Employe.findAllByService(direction)
```

or something along those lines.